# How to clear log files periodically?

Tags: shell-script, files, timestamps, input

I am new to shell scripting. I want to clear log files in a directory based on the dates. I have managed to gather this code:

```
DIR1='/home/u01/app/oracle/servers/DIR1/logs'
DIR2='home/u01/app/oracle/servers/DIR2/logs'
DIR3='home/u01/app/oracle/servers/DIR3/logs'
Admin='/home/u01/app/oracle/fmw/admin_poc001/domain/domain_IAM_POC01/servers/AdminServer/logs'

echo "Enter the path"
read path
if [ $path == $DIR1 || $path == $DIR2 || $path == DIR3 || $path == $Admin ]
then
  echo  $path "check your path"

find $path -mtime +10 --# This line here "10" represents listing out the last 10 days logs
for i in *.log* *.out*
do
  cat /dev/null >"$i"
done
else
echo "Re-enter the Correct path"
read path
fi
```

This script gives me output  when I give input like this:

```
Enter your path :
/home/u01/app/oracle/servers/DIR1/logs
```

It will clear all the log files until the date of running that script.

But I want that if I run this script I can clear the log files for times *other* than the last 10 days, i.e., if I run this today (24/06/2015), then I can clear the log files before the date 14/06/2015.

Also: rather than entering the full directory path, can I store that in a variable and just type that variable name (instead of entering the full directory path)?

For example, instead of entering `/home/u01/app/oracle/servers/DIR1/logs` I am looking for a procedure where I can just enter *DIR1* so that it can go into that directory without the total path.

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool called `logrotate` read the manual page `man logrotate` it is started by cron and probably already cleaning the log directory you can add your own configurataion files to `/etc/logrotate.d`

Comment: probably not configured to do the ones in `home` directory, but you can run it manually, or add configuration.

Comment: Note that `logrotate` may or may not be available on the concerned OS, which is not stated clearly in OP.

Comment: Hi thanks for response but can you please elaborate about this, as i am very new to shell scripting , what are the configuration files and i need to clear all *.log files and *.out files based on the date and day which has to clear the log files accordingly.thanks in advance. please share an example script if anyone has

Comment: have you read the manual page for logrotate yet ? whenyou try something and get stuck, write a new question.